# How to use clpfd in eclipseCLP prolog (no eclipse java IDE)

Tags: prolog, clpfd, eclipse-clp

I'm trying to make a simple route plan with CLP in prolog using [eclipseclp](http://eclipseclp.org)
and I want to use the clpfd prolog library, but the compiler doesn't recognize them. I obtain this error:

```
library not found in use_module(library(clpfd))
```

I have installed all the third party libraries of eclipseCLP but I can't solve this problem.

Comment: maybe `:- lib(clpfd).`?

Comment: maybe `:- lib(ic).`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several libraries you could use, but you probably want to start with either the [interval solver](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic/index.html), which is loaded with

```
:- lib(ic).           % or :- use_module(library(ic)).
```

or the [Gecode interface](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/gfd/index.html)

```
:- lib(gfd).          % or :- use_module(library(gfd)).
```

Both implement the basic CLP(FD) functionality.  Sooner or later you will have to consult the manual.